# Set column name with rows value on MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is my sql query on database MySQL:

```
SELECT
    sRdt 
    COUNT(*) AS sNumber,
    sYear
FROM
    `doTable`
GROUP BY
    sRdt,
    sYear;
```

And this is the output:

```
+------+-------+---------+
| sRdt | sYear | sNumber |
+------+-------+---------+
| UOT  | 2014  |      62 |
| UOT  | 2015  |     377 |
| UOT  | 2016  |    4941 |
| UOT  | 2017  |    1426 |
+------+-------+---------+
```

How to do for have this other output instead?

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| sRdt | 2014  | 2015  | 2016  | 2017  |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| UOT  |    62 |  377  | 4941  | 1426  |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: You also can automate query building for different years, have a look at this article - [Automating data pivoting, creating query dynamically](http://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with some conditional sums:

```
select  sRdt,
        sum(case when sYear = 2014 then 1 end) as col_2014,
        sum(case when sYear = 2015 then 1 end) as col_2015,
        sum(case when sYear = 2016 then 1 end) as col_2016,
        sum(case when sYear = 2017 then 1 end) as col_2017
from    doTable
group by sRdt
```